# What does curly bracket after a trait definition name mean in scala?

Tags: scala

While using `Future` I have seen people use

```
Future{
      Thread sleep 500
      promise success "You've just completed the promise with me in it!"
 }
```

Looking at the definition of `Future`, I can see that Future is a trait

But when I make my own trait, Example:

```
trait t{}
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    t{
        println("Test")
    }
}
```

It does not compile. Why?

Comment: Why is the title of your question so much diifferent to your actual question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you write `Future{ /*your code*/ }` then the `apply` method of the companion object of `Future` is called.

the signature of the `Future`'s apply method is the following

```
def apply[T](body:=>T)
```

You can see that the `apply` method is called when you do `ctrl+click` or `cmd+click` on the `Future` in an IDE such as InteliJ.

Your trait `t` does not have an apply. Therefore that piece of code does not compile.

```
trait t{}
object t{
  apply[T](body:=>T){}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for Future you describe comes from the trait companion object.

This object has the following method :

```
  def apply[T](body: =>T)(implicit @deprecatedName('execctx) executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] =
    unit.map(_ => body)
```

The accepted argument being a function returning a T, it's perfectly idiomatic to pass it via the form you see, which is a bracketed code block.

This being said, you can kind of instantiate your traits (by creating anonymous subclasses of them), the following compile :

```
trait t {}

object MyApp extends App {
  new t {
    println("Test")
  }
}
```

I would not recommend it as a general good practice though, but it has its uses.